# Change top/right/bottom/left of item of layer-list programmatically

Tags: android, drawable, layer-list

I have a `layer-list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="+id/item_2"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now I want to change some property of items like `(top,right)` at runtime. I able to change the color of the shape inside the item by

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) v.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_list);
GradientDrawable drawable2 = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.item_2);
drawable2.setColor(strokeColor[0]);
```

but I don't know how to change `top,right`. How can I change it?
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try with this method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInset(int, int, int, int, int)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).